sudoers nopasswd faulty on debian 12?
I have troubles with setting up a python script that should run as root, but without asking for password.
It is not the first time that I do it, but this time it fails on Debian 12
What I have already tried:

try with an executable instead of a script : same behaviour
try on another Debian 12 system : same behaviour
try on Linux Mint, Fedora : working without issue

So there is no typo or line order issue in /etc/sudoers ...
Here is the last line of my /etc/sudoers file :
ivan All=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/veracrypt, /home/ivan/helloSudo.sh

Example:
ivan@miniLab:~$ sudo ./helloSudo.sh
[sudo] Mot de passe de ivan :
sudo: il est nécessaire de saisir un mot de passe
ivan@miniLab:~$ sudo veracrypt
[sudo] Mot de passe de ivan :
sudo: il est nécessaire de saisir un mot de passe

=> so password is required for helloSudo.sh and veracrypt
helloSudo.sh:
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/ivan/hello.py

hello.py
import os
import getpass
msg=f"Hello World from {getpass.getuser()}"  
print (msg)


ivan@miniLab:~$ sudo /usr/bin/veracrypt
[sudo] Mot de passe de ivan : 
sudo: il est nécessaire de saisir un mot de passe

=> same problem when providing full path !
I just tried on a new fresh installation of Debian 12, and it works. So my 2 existing installation of Debian 12 have an issue.
Any Idea about how to find out what is going on ?
ivan@miniLab:~$ sudo -l
[sudo] Mot de passe de ivan : 
Entrées Defaults correspondant pour ivan sur miniLab :
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin, use_pty

Paramètres par défaut de runas ou spécifiques aux commandes pour ivan :
    Defaults!/usr/lib/*/libexec/kf5/kdesu_stub !use_pty

L'utilisateur ivan peut utiliser les commandes suivantes sur miniLab :
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

=> in English
ivan@miniLab:~$ sudo -l
[sudo] ivan password : 
Corresponding Defaults entries for ivan on miniLab:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin, use_pty

Default runas or command-specific parameters for ivan :
    Defaults!/usr/lib/*/libexec/kf5/kdesu_stub !use_pty

The ivan user can use the following commands on miniLab:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

After fixing the typo, sudo -l gives now :
...
L'utilisateur ivan peut utiliser les commandes suivantes sur miniLab :
(ALL : ALL) ALL
(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/veracrypt, /home/ivan/helloSudo.sh


Note that sudo entries like this use the full path to the executable.  If there are multiple copies and you run it with the wrong path, the sudo entry won't be used.  So when you update your question to include the sudo entry, also include the command line you are using to run your program with it.

Also - you are elevating by running visudo. I assume sudo is configured to keep your password in memory, and is therefore not asking for any of the following commands.

ok, good point Panki, so it is the reason why it is working just after sudo visudo -f /etc/fstab !

Please post the full sudo -l output, because other config lines in the file might conflict or match earlier.

@StephenHarris ok, sudo -l posted. Good evening !

I wonder if it matters that that line in sudoers says All rather than ALL in one place?  I.e., whether it's a simple typo that is the issue.

@Kusalananda Wow thank you so much ! that was this simple typo ! I am sorry I wrote that I was sure it was not a typo issue !
Thank you everybody, I was very pleasantly surprised to see that you took the time to look into my problem.
Kusalananda, good pāramī for you ;)
How do I mark this thread as solved ?

Yeah, the     (ALL : ALL) ALL in the sudo -l output shows the expansion of all the rules, so the explicit rule you tried to create wasn't being applied.

@Stephen Harris see my last edit. After fixing the typo, it works now !

From the question:
ivan All=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/veracrypt, /home/ivan/helloSudo.sh

Note the casing of the word All.  This should be ALL, with two upper-cased L.
